# Change interpreter options Zeppelin EMR

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a cloudformation stack with some bootstraps and spark steps. I would like to launch my EMR and by default the Interpreter will be configured like this:
The interpreter will be instantiated **Per User**  in **Isolated**  process.

I just want to know in configuration files where could i change that in order to put it in bootstrap actions an replace in bootstraping stage.